# JSON to a Map Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a json file (scoreChannel.json) and I want to convert it to a map. 
My JSON is currently:

```
{
}
```

So what it should do is turn my map (something like this):

```
guildID:channelID
12345678:9876531
12312321:123123123
```

and write it to a JSON so its like this:

```
    {
  "12312321": 123123123,
  "12345678": 9876531,
  "guildID": "channelID"
   }
```

And also be able to go from that back to a map that I can use normally. Like being able to do:

```
map.delete();
map.set();
map.get();
etc
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Object `Map` to store key-value pairs.

```js
let file = `guildID:channelID
12345678:9876531
12312321:123123123`;

let map = file.split("\n").reduce((a, c) => {  
  let [key, value] = c.split(":");
  a.set(key, value);
  return a;
}, new Map());

console.log(map.get("12345678"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What's the CSS for? The OP tagged the question node.js

Comment: @jro that’s just to expand the Stackoverflow’s console.

Comment: I see. Learnt something new today!